# How to use PHP Loop to allocate persons with roles

Tags: php

I am trying to go about this, I have  a list of 4 persons, and a single role that each person has to do when its their turn to do.

**Day versus Persons:**

```
Day1-Allan
Day2-Mary
Day3-Kevin
Day4-Alex

Day5-Allan
Day6-Mary
Day7-Kevin
Day8-Alex

.....and so on
```

The roles repeat the cycle once everyone has had their day.
So `foreach` day, only 1 person can do the task.

How can I implement this in PHP?
Something like

```
foreach($person): //on this day
//do your role
endforeach;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow :) What exactly are you trying to achieve? A long list of days with their allocated person? A way to lookup a particular day to see which person? Give us an example of what you expect the *output* of your program to look like. Edit: Sorry, presumed you were new, says you've been around for a year!

Comment: Foreach day, 1 person does a role. A person cannot do the role until every other has done it, complete cycle

Comment: It is not possible using foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that

```
$names = array('Allan', 'Mary', 'Kevin', 'Alex');
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
  echo "Day" . ($i+1) . "-" . $names[$i%4] . "<br/>";
}
```

If you want to add space between cycles

```
$names = array('Allan', 'Mary', 'Kevin', 'Alex');
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
  echo "Day" . ($i+1) . "-" . $names[$i%4] . "<br/>";
  if ($i%4 == 3) {
    echo "<br/>";
  }
}
```

A more evolutive solution

```
$names = array('Allan', 'Mary', 'Kevin', 'Alex');
$number_of_days = 100;
$number_of_people = count($names);
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_days; $i++) {
  echo "Day" . ($i+1) . "-" . $names[$i%$number_of_people] . "<br/>";
  if ($i%$number_of_people == 3) {
    echo "<br/>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You can do the basic version using...

```
$people = array ('Allan', 'Mary', 'Kevin', 'Alex');
$day = 1;
foreach ( $people as $person )  {
    echo "Day {$day} - {$person}".PHP_EOL;
    $day+=1;
}
```

So create an array of people and `foreach` takes one element of the array at a time.

This outputs...

```
Day 1 - Allan
Day 2 - Mary
Day 3 - Kevin
Day 4 - Alex
```